# Basis of Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and suppose that $B$ is a basis for the topology $X$.

> We write $\Omega B$ for the collection $\Omega$ of all union of elements of $B$.

Could someone please explain what this means?

Is it all possible collections? Like $\phi$ with elements of basis also belongs to the collection $\Omega B$?

Comment: I've improved the formatting, but could you be a bit clearer about what you are confused about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what it means.

As a preliminary, the word "collection" is just an alternate word for "set". I am going to avoid the word "collection" and simply use the word "set".

First, every element of the set $B$ is a subset of $X$.

Second, suppose I have a subset $C \subset B$. So, every element of $C$ is a subset of $X$. So I can take the union of all the elements of $C$, and I will get another subset of $X$. Let's denote that as $\cup C$. To be precise:
$$\cup C = \{x \in X \mid \text{there exists $c \in C$ such that $x \in c$}\}
$$
Now define
$$\Omega B = \{\cup C \mid C \subset B\}
$$

Now that quote you gave is quite imprecise, hard to understand, and, well, bad.

As an exercise in bad mathematical writing, I'll work backwards from my precise definition of $\Omega B$, expressing that definition in less and less precise words.

First, I can say:

> $\Omega B$ is the set of all unions of the elements of some subset of $B$.

Next, to be still less precise, I'll rewrite "the elements of some subset of $B$" as "some of the elements of $B$", and I get:

> $\Omega B$ is the set of all unions of some of the elements of $B$.

Next, I'll de-emphasize three words:

> $\Omega B$ is the set of all unions of (some of the) elements of $B$.

Then I'll completely remove those de-emphasized words:

> $\Omega B$ is the set of all unions of elements of $B$.

Next, I'll replace "set" by "collection", and I'll violate grammatical rules by dropping the $s$ from the end of "unions":

> $\Omega B$ is the collection of all union of elements of $B$.

Finally, I'll throw $\Omega$ into the sentence in a random meaningless way, and I get the final really bad version:

> $\Omega B$ is the collection $\Omega$ of all union of elements of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at an example.

Let $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and equip $X$ with the following topology $\tau$,

$$\tau=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{c\},\{a,b,c\},\{c,d,a\},\{a,c\}\}$$

Then $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space. One possible basis for this space is

$$\mathcal{B}=\{\{a\},\{c\},\{a,b,c\},\{c,d,a\}\}$$

Note that not every element of $\tau$ is an element of $\mathcal{B}$. If we use the notation $\Omega$ for the collection of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, we mean that every element of $\Omega$ is the union of some elements of $\mathcal{B}$ (potentially an empty union!).

For example, the set $\{a,c\}$ is in $\Omega$ because

$$\{a,c\}=\{a\}\cup\{c\}$$

The sets $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$ are elements of $\mathcal{B}$, so their union $\{a\}\cup\{c\}=\{a,c\}$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ and is therefore in $\Omega$. Similarly,

$$X=\{c,d,a\}\cup\{a,b,c\}$$

because $\{c,d,a\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$ are in $\mathcal{B}$ we have that $X\in\Omega$. The unions that make up elements of $\tau$ don't have to be restricted to finite unions. They can be arbitrary! For example now let us take $X=\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$, the natural numbers, and let us define our basis $\mathcal{B}$ to be the set of all singletons, that is

$$\mathcal{B}=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots\}$$

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. Then the set of all even numbers $E=\{2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$ is an element of $\Omega$. To see this we note that given an even number $k$, we have that $\{k\}\in\mathcal{B}$. Then

$$E=\{2\}\cup\{4\}\cup\{6\}\cup\{8\}\cup\cdots=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{2i\}$$

As each singleton $\{2i\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{B}$ we have that $E\in\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of subsets of $X$ that form the base for a topology, then this topology is given by, sort of following your notation,

$$\Omega \mathcal{B}= \{ \bigcup \mathcal{C}: \mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{B}\}$$

the set of all unions of subsets of $\mathcal{B}$. This subset of which we take the union could be $\mathcal{C}=\emptyset$, in which case we get the set $\emptyset = \bigcup \emptyset \in \Omega \mathcal{B}$ or the other extreme case $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{B}$ and then we get $X = \bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \Omega \mathcal{B}$ (one of the conditions on being a base is exactly that the base elements have $X$ as their union, which is clearly necessary, otherwise we could never get $X$ in $\Omega \mathcal{B}$, which then cannot be the generated topology, of course). But in general there are many more possible subsets of $\mathcal{B}$, all whose unions also lie in this $\Omega \mathcal{B}$ as well.